# Change Tableau's Automatic Labels for a Text Table

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, tableau-desktop

I am making a small summary table in Tableau. I want the full date to be shown (day, month, and year), but when I select the DAY() option, it changes the column title from "Date Initiated" to "Day of Date Initiated" which makes no sense. How can I change the column title in this Tableau table?

[image]

When I right click, I don't have an "Edit Alias" option like I would for a non-date column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ways:
1.You can change the data type from Date to String.  This will show the full date and you can also alias, if needed.

2.You can create a calculated field using STR(Date Initiated).  Same as above, this will show the full date and you can also alias, if needed.

3.You can use the discrete custom date part Month / Day / Year option using the Custom date selection in the dimension dropdown menu.  See images.

[image: Select More -> Custom]

[image: Select Month / Day / Year]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is a hack (as always in Tableau) :

1. Change the **format** of your date to **TEXT**.
2. **Insert your data** into your tab.
3. Go to "Data source" and change the **format** to **Date**.

You should see your date values displayed correctly as **DD/MM/YYYY**.